# get the most recent data using JPQL

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring a JPA repository that uses a table with year and a month columns. I need to get the most recent data available. The records are not ordered by year and month (the max. id will not return the most recent data). In SQL would be something like:

```
WITH max_year AS(
SELECT month, MAX(year) as MostRecentYear FROM table
)
SELECT MAX(month), MostRecentYear FROM max_year;
```

I cannot used native JPA query methods because the names of the table columns are not the same than the entity attribute names.

Comment: If the query you provided works natively in Mysql, you could use it as a [nativeQuery](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query).

Answer (score 0):

In the end, using JPA native method worked:

```
POJO findFirstByOrderByYearDescMonthDesc();
```

However, it returns the whole object, not only year and month attributes.